# Magento2 : Admin module Image upload code to display form

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I have magento2 admin custom module with image upload functionality. I want to upload image from admin. what code should apply for display image field in from, upload image, also image display in edit action.

Thanks

File Path : `app\code\[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Emp\Edit\Tab\Main.php`

```
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
    */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('emp_post');

        $isElementDisabled = false;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Employee Information')]);

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('customer_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'customer_id']);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'firstname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'firstname',
                'label' => __('First Name'),
                'title' => __('First Name'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'value' =>'abc'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'lastname',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'lastname',
                'label' => __('Last Name'),
                'title' => __('Last Name'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'value' =>'abc'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'email',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'email',
                'label' => __('Email Address'),
                'title' => __('Email Address'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'value' =>'abc'
            ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'image',
            'image',
            array(
                'name' => 'image',
                'label' => __('Image'),
                'title' => __('Image')
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'telephone',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'telephone',
                'label' => __('Telephone'),
                'title' => __('Telephone'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'value' =>'abc'
            ]
        );

        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(
            \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'dob',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'dob',
                'label' => __('Date of birth'),
                'date_format' => $dateFormat,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'class' => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'is_active',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'name' => 'is_active',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray(),
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_active', $isElementDisabled ? '0' : '1');
        }


        if($model->getData('image')){
            $model->setData('image','learning/images'.$model->getData('image'));
        }

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Comment: The module developed https://darshanbhavsar.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/magento-2-custom-module/ looks to have everything you are looking for.

Answer (score 18):

You need to create a class to handle your image upload field and show the image once is uploaded.

So create `[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper\Image` class

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image as ImageField;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory as ElementFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory as ElementCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use [Namespace]\[Module]\Model\[Entity]\Image as [Entity]Image;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

/**
 * @method string getValue()
 */
class Image extends ImageField
{
    /**
     * image model
     *
     * @var \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\[Entity]\Image
     */
    protected $imageModel;

    /**
     * @param [Entity]Image $imageModel
     * @param ElementFactory $factoryElement
     * @param ElementCollectionFactory $factoryCollection
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        [Entity]Image $imageModel,
        ElementFactory $factoryElement,
        ElementCollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        Escaper $escaper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->imageModel = $imageModel;
        parent::__construct($factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $escaper, $urlBuilder, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Get image preview url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getUrl()
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->imageModel->getBaseUrl().$this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

then create the class that will help you retrieve the image upload path and upload dir

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Model\[Entity];
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Image
{
    /**
     * media sub folder
     * @var string
     */
    protected $subDir = '[namespace]/[module]/[entity]';
    /**
     * url builder
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
     */
    protected $fileSystem;
    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param Filesystem $fileSystem
     */
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        Filesystem $fileSystem
    )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    }
    /**
     * get images base url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]).$this->subDir.'/image';
    }
    /**
     * get base image dir
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseDir()
    {
        return $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath($this->subDir.'/image');
    }
}
```

now in your edit for tab add this in the method `_prepareForm` right after declaring the fieldset

```
$fieldset->addType('image', '\[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper\Image');
```

and add your image field like this

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'image_field_name',
    'image',
    [
        'name'        => 'image_field_name',
        'label'       => __('Image field Label'),
        'title'       => __('Image field Label'),
    ]
);
```

In the controller that saves your entity you need to inject in the constructor the following classes

`Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory` and `[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\[Entity]\Image`

So make your class look like this

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException as FrameworkException;

class ....

protected $uploaderFactory;
protected $imageModel;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\[Entity]\Image $imageModel,
    ....
){
    ...
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->imageModel = $imageModel;
    ...
}
```

Now, in the same controller add this, before calling `$[entity]->save()`

```
$imageName = $this->uploadFileAndGetName('image_field_name', $this->imageModel->getBaseDir(), $data);
$[entity]->setImageFieldName($imageName);
```

and create this method:

```
public function uploadFileAndGetName($input, $destinationFolder, $data)
{
    try {
        if (isset($data[$input]['delete'])) {
            return '';
        } else {
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $input]);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($destinationFolder);
            return $result['file'];
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() != \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
            throw new FrameworkException($e->getMessage());
        } else {
            if (isset($data[$input]['value'])) {
                return $data[$input]['value'];
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

A full example on how to create an entity that supports image and file upload (it's a bit different than described here as it contains an extra class for upload) [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule/)

Comment: given url exension not working. it throw error on screen exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source class "\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Collection" for "Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory" generation does not exist.'

Comment: @SHPatel. Clear the contents of var/generation. If this problem persists it can for 2 reasons. You either don't have the latest version of Magento 2 or my extension does not work on the latest version. If the problem is my extension I will check it when I have some time.

Comment: @Marius, How can we display such image into `adminhtml Grid` section too? Right now is Default magento 2 is showing it for `Product Grid`.

Comment: @PrafulRajput. I didn't get to check that part out yet. I have no idea how it's done.

Comment: @marius this works in RC 2. One thing you mention adding $fieldset->addType('image', '\[Namespace]\[Module]\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper\Image'); I am pretty sure you are missing a "Block" callout. \[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper\Image

Comment: @Eirik. Thanks for spotting this. I fixed it.

Comment: I think `throw new FrameworkException` should be `throw new \PHPUnit_Framework_Exception` (the former is undefined relative to the current namespace). Also if you're implementing this, don't forget to update all `image_field_name`s with your own, including the camelcase `setImageFieldName()` in the controller (I lost some time to that one)

Comment: i'm getting this error while saving form Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on null any idea? @Marius

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @Marius I have used above code. It working fine for all allowed file but throws exception if disallowed file-type is tried to upload. Can you help me to manage exception.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal wrap the call to  `$imageName = $this->uploadFileAndGetName ...` in a `try-catch` and on `catch` do something with the exception message. Set it as a flash message or something

Comment: @Marius I am trying to implement a similar situation. I have my `Save` class which `extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action` When I update my `__constructor` to include `(Action\Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        SliderImage $imageModel)` I get the error `Save::__construct() must be an instance of .../UploaderFactory, none given` I have debuged a bit and it seems like only the `Context` is ever being injected. Any idea?

Comment: clear var/generation or generated/code depending on your version

Comment: I get this error on save post Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\Phrase, string given, called in /[...]/app/code/Altravista/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php on line 101

Comment: Should i guess what's on line 101? Also, how is this related to my nswer.....anyway.... you are thriwing an exception that receives as parameter a string when it should receive an instance of `Magento\\Framework\\Phrase`. How do I know that.... it says so in the error message. Wrap that text in `__(...)`

Comment: Thanks for this Marius, I have followed and it almost works for me and image is uploaded i just need to get the filename to save into the database and i get an array to string conversion error. Not sure how to add $imageName to my $data as not sure on the last part of setImageFieldName in my context any ideas?

Comment: Dw i figured it out your an absolute legend!

Comment: Everything works fine, but when edit a form and saved it image save as blank in database how to recover it

Comment: it reflects  Notice: Undefined variable: data error

Comment: Hi Marius, Can you please help with multi upload in the same code.

Answer (score 3):

Admin module for basic add/update news is [here](https://darshanbhavsar.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/magento-2-custom-module/).
In case you are looking for simple image upload solution look at the following snippet which is taken from the [link](http://webkul.com/blog/how-to-upload-image-in-magento2/).

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
    Action\Context $context     
) {
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute(){
    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
    $path = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
    ->getAbsolutePath('images/');
    $uploader->save($path);
}
```

Comment: _filesystem not definded :(

Comment: found it, we need to add this to work, also create it in construct() function as well
use \Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

Comment: Replace _filesystem by $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')

Comment: @divyasekar Can you please answer this question? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287175/saved-image-in-the-admin-grid-is-not-fetching-while-editing-the-grid-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

You could add image field in _prepareForm() method of your admin form:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'imagefieldname',
    'image',
    array(
        'name' => 'imagefieldname',
        'label' => __('Image'),
        'title' => __('Image')
    )

  );
```

Comment: @chanresh image field added done but i need to display image preview on form.

Comment: If you upload image and save the record then it will show small thumbnail near "Choose File" input file field.

Comment: I have uplode image and save it but thumbnail image can't display.

Comment: Please add your code snippet for _prepareForm().

Comment: check my question, question updated with _prepareForm().

Comment: _prepareForm() code seems fine.

Comment: Now you could check weather image is being saved or not. If image is being saved then you should check that you are saving Model data for record in execute() method of Edit action in Controller using registry object. $registryObject = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');$registryObject->register('emp_post', $model);

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link for admin custom form image upload

[admin custom form image upload magento 2](https://sdivya.home.blog)