# Magento 2: How to add a browse button to upload file in admin section?

Tags: magento2, module, admin, file-upload

Working on Magento 2 custom module implementation and want to add a `browse button` to upload a file in admin form.

I have gone through the

[Magento2 : Admin module Image upload code to display form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86125/magento2-admin-moduel-image-upload-code-to-display-form)

but it's not working for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: pls show code and error. u can get error in var/log/system.log .

Comment: I added the error. please see

Comment: i things field image is not true or null.  U should check $data before save.

Comment: Please update your question with your code, it's like we have to imagine how is your code which is absolutely different with the code inside the reference link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }
After This Add the below code

 if(is_array( $data['image'])){
                $data['image']=implode(" ",$data['image']);

                $model->setData($data);

            }
            else {
                $model->setData($data);
            }
```

Do this thing it will solve ur issue