# Image path not saving in database with Custom Module

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, magento-2.0.7

I've created a custom grid module and now I am trying to create and upload image for the Form.php. When I save it the image it gets uploaded to the right location which is  but it does not save the path in the database.

I am following this thread [Marius's Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86125/magento2-admin-module-image-upload-code-to-display-form#answer-86262.)

Sorry I can not comment on Marius's post, I don't have enough reputation.
Can anyone help me with this please? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: @Jay. Thank's for your edit suggestion it's really helpfull, I wonder if you can really help me with this issue please?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue why it wasn't saving the path I realize that
it was because the function setImageFieldName `$[entity]->setImageFieldName($imageName);`
didn't exit in my `model\[Entity]` so I created one.

e.g:

```
public function setImageFieldName()
{
    return $this->getData(self::IMAGE);
}
```